# Error testing Parse Promise and $http request together

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, http, parse-platform, promise

I'm trying to test a code that waits for a Promise before calling http:

Code:

```
function foo() {
  return Parse.Promise.as(1).then(function(one) {
    return $http.get('/bar');
  });
}
```

Test:

```
describe('foo', function() {
  it('gets', function(done) {
    $httpBackend.expect('GET', '/bar').respond(200);
    foo().then(function(res) {
      expect(res.status).to.be.equal(200);
      done();
    });
    $httpBackend.flush();
  });
});
```

Error:

```
1) gets
     foo
     No pending request to flush !
```

My guess is that beacuse `Parse.Promise` delays the promise resolution, and the http request wasn't made when the `$httpBackend.flush` is called.

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

Mocha actually has promise syntax support, you can just test promises directly by dropping the `done` parameter and returning the promise:

```
describe('foo', function() {
  it('gets', function() { // no `done`
    try { 
      $httpBackend.expect('GET', '/bar').respond(200);
      return foo().then(function(res) { // return here
        expect(res.status).to.be.equal(200);
      });
    } finally {
      $httpBackend.flush();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: But you gotta call `$httpBackend.flush` for the `$http.get` promise to be resolved. When will you do that?

Comment: @gfpacheco oh right, you need to call that since you're mocking httpBackend, lemme amend that

Answer (score 0):

By default Parse Promise [delays to the next tick or with timeout 0](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-JS/blob/617be9f3c948a50e0239e5734e3286ca14aa9490/src/ParsePromise.js#L162).

You can disable this behavior calling `Parse.Promise.disableAPlusCompliant();` before your test.

Comment: This will break the order of execution of your code and you might get unexplained failures.

Comment: You can disable it for a single test only if you want. It was the only way I could make it work after searching for hours.